# Convert grayscale HImage (MVtec Halcon library) to c# bitmap

Tags: image-processing, halcon

Is there an easy way to convert the grayscale Halcon/MVtec Himage object to a c# bitmap?  Sample code exists [here (mvtec  documentation)](https://www.mvtec.com/doc/halcon/13/en/interleave_channels.html) for a color image:

```
  HTuple type, width, height;
  HImage patras = new HImage("patras");

  HImage interleaved = patras.InterleaveChannels("argb", "match", 255);
  IntPtr ptr = interleaved.GetImagePointer1(out type, out width, out height);

  Image img = new Bitmap(width/4, height, width,
                         PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb, ptr);

  pictureBox.Image = img;
```

But from this sample, it is not clear how I can work with grayscale images.

Comment: the link to your sample code does not work. please edit your post please, thank you :)

Comment: thanks for pointing this out,  I fixed the link.

Answer (score 1):

I have researched your problem and at this link, https://multipix.com/supportblog/halcon-bitmap-himage-conversion/ it explains how to create a bitmap object for both RBG channel and **single channels** which is what you are looking for.

It states:

> The creation of a bitmap from a HALCON image can be done through the constructors of the bitmap class. With single channel images this is straight forward by using the pointer from the operator get_image_pointer1 and the dimensions of the image.

I believe this means that it is the exact same format as the sample code you have given, but you just remove the line `HImage interleaved = patras.InterleaveChannels("argb", "match", 255);`

Your code will probably look like this if `patras` is a gray scale image:

```
HTuple type, width, height;
HImage patras = new HImage("patras");
IntPtr ptr = patras.GetImagePointer1(out type, out width, out height);
Image img = new Bitmap(width/4, height, width, PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale, ptr);

pictureBox.Image = img;
```

Comment: I didn't test, but I don't think this is correct, because PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb is clearly a color image?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change that. I have edited my answer again. Please tell me if there’s anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot directly create 8-bit grayscale bitmap, the quickest way would be to convert gray image into RGB:

```
        HImage hiImageNew = new HImage();
        hiImageNew = hiImage.Compose3(hiImage, hiImage);

        hiImageNew = hiImageNew.InterleaveChannels("argb", "match", 255);
        IntPtr ptr = hiImageNew.GetImagePointer1(out htType, out htWidth, out htHeight);
        System.Drawing.Image bImage = new Bitmap(htWidth/4, htHeight, htWidth, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb, ptr);
```

Comment: this might be "quickest" from a code point of view, but I work with very high res images, and the difference between read/writing a whole color image  to disk and a grayscale image is huge.  I am still testing @Catherine answer which may be acceptable for ym case even though it is 16bpp grayscale.

Comment: Why are you not just saving HImages directly without conversion to Bitmap?

Comment: we would like to return the Bitmap to the Middleware of our application where it may either be saved to disk or the DB.  However we don't want to expose the HImage type to the rest of the application.

Answer (score 1):

check this:
 https://github.com/Joncash/HanboAOMClassLibrary/blob/master/Hanbo.Helper/ImageConventer.cs

In this Class you can find the function in which you can choose if you have a grayscale or rgb image

```
public static Bitmap ConvertHalconImageToBitmap(HObject halconImage, bool isColor)
```

Comment: This should be the answer, just copy pasting that file and having all the required conversions