# Convert HImage to byte[] as File.ReadAllBytes() does with .png

Tags: c#, machine-learning, halcon

```cs
HalconDotNet.HOperatorSet.ReadImage(out HObject image, srcPath);
//...
//(graphic stuff)
//...
HalconDotNet.HOperatorSet.WriteImage(imagePart, "png", 0, tmpImgPath); // skip these steps
Image = File.ReadAllBytes(path)                                        // skip these steps
```

This piece of code is executed thousands of times. The last two steps are just there to have a compatibility step in between Halcon and .NET as I dont know how to combine them.

What I need is a way to convert a `HImage(HObject)` to a `byte[]`, the same way `WriteImage()` + `File.ReadAllBytes(path)` would do. This last bit is important as this piece of code generates inputs for image classification models.

As the models are trained with data loaded from disk with `File.ReadAllBytes(path)` I'm assuming I need to prepare the data in the same way when using the model. When I read a 100x100 color PNG (solid color) with `File.ReadAllBytes()` I don't get 100x100x3 bytes, but 342, so I'm assuming the data is still compressed, and further assuming that I need to guarantee similar data when using the model.

This question has some overlap with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282049/convert-grayscale-himage-mvtec-halcon-library-to-c-sharp-bitmap) but I need a byte[] instead of bitmap and just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

an other way could be to convert your hImage to a bitmap and then serialize this bitmap as a byte array.

heres a function to convert a hImage to a System.Drawing.Bitmap

```
public static Bitmap HImageToBitmap(HImage ho_Image) {
        int iWidth, iHeight, iNumChannels;
        IntPtr ip_R, ip_G, ip_B, ip_Gray;
        String sType;
        // null return object
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            //
            // Note that pixel data is stored differently in System.Drawing.Bitmap
            // a) Stride:
            // stride is the width, rounded up to a multiple of 4 (padding)
            // Size of data array HALCON: heigth*width, Bitmap: heigth*stride
            // compare: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy1a2d14%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
            // b) RGB data
            // HALCON: three arrays, Bitmap: one array (alternating red/green/blue)
            iNumChannels = ho_Image.CountChannels();
            if (iNumChannels != 1 && iNumChannels != 3)
                throw new Exception("Conversion of HImage to Bitmap failed. Number of channels of the HImage is: " +
                    iNumChannels + ". Conversion rule exists only for images with 1 or 3 chanels");
            if (iNumChannels == 1) {
                //
                // 1) Get the image pointer
                ip_Gray = ho_Image.GetImagePointer1(out sType, out iWidth, out iHeight);
                //
                // 2) Calculate the stride
                int iPadding = (4 - (iWidth % 4)) % 4;
                int iStride = iWidth + iPadding;
                //
                // 3) Create a new gray Bitmap object, allocating the necessary (managed) memory 
                bitmap = new Bitmap(iWidth, iHeight, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
                // note for high performance: in case of padding=0, image can be copied by reference.
                // however, then the bitmap's validity relies on the HImage lifetime.
                // bitmap = new Bitmap(iWidth, iHeight, iWidth, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed, ip_Gray);
                //
                // 4) Copy the image data directly into the bitmap data object, re-arranged in the required bitmap order
                // BitmapData lets us access the data in memory
                BitmapData bmpData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, iWidth, iHeight),
                    ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
                // System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel processing requires .NET framework >= 4.0 
                Parallel.For(0, iHeight, r => {
                    IntPtr posRead = ip_Gray + r * iWidth;
                    IntPtr posWrite = bmpData.Scan0 + r * iStride;
                    for (int c = 0; c < iWidth; c++)
                        Marshal.WriteByte((IntPtr)posWrite, c, Marshal.ReadByte((IntPtr)posRead, c));
                });
                //
                // 5) Let the windows memory management take over control
                bitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);
                //
                // 6) Adjust palette to grayscale (linearized grayscale)
                // ColorPalette has no constructor -> obtain it from the static member
                ColorPalette cp_P = bitmap.Palette;
                for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
                    cp_P.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(i, i, i);
                }
                bitmap.Palette = cp_P;
            }
            if (iNumChannels == 3) {
                //
                // 1) Get the image pointer
                ho_Image.GetImagePointer3(out ip_R, out ip_G, out ip_B, out sType, out iWidth, out iHeight);
                //
                // 2) Calculate the stride
                int iPadding = (4 - ((iWidth * 3) % 4)) % 4;
                int iStride = iWidth * 3 + iPadding;
                //
                // 3) Create a new RGB Bitmap object, allocating the necessary (managed) memory 
                bitmap = new Bitmap(iWidth, iHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
                //
                // 4) Copy the image data directly into the bitmap data object, re-arranged in the required bitmap order
                // BitmapData lets us access the data in memory
                BitmapData bmpData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, iWidth, iHeight),
                ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
                Parallel.For(0, iHeight, r => {
                    IntPtr posReadR = (IntPtr)((long)ip_R + r * iWidth);
                    IntPtr posReadG = (IntPtr)((long)ip_G + r * iWidth);
                    IntPtr posReadB = (IntPtr)((long)ip_B + r * iWidth);
                    IntPtr posWrite = (IntPtr)((long)bmpData.Scan0 + r * iStride);
                    for (int c = 0; c < iWidth; c++) {
                        Marshal.WriteByte(posWrite, 3 * c, Marshal.ReadByte(posReadB, c));
                        Marshal.WriteByte(posWrite, 3 * c + 1, Marshal.ReadByte(posReadG, c));
                        Marshal.WriteByte(posWrite, 3 * c + 2, Marshal.ReadByte(posReadR, c));
                    }
                });
                //
                // 5) Let the windows memory management take over control
                bitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new Exception("Conversion of HImage to Bitmap failed.", ex);
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try?

```
public static byte[] ImageToByte(Image image)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Or

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(imagePath);

byte[] byteArr = new byte[] { };

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    image.Save(ms, image.RawFormat);
    byteArr = ms.ToArray();
}
```

For Image you will need System.Drawing

Comment: Thanks for helping, maybe I'm not seeing it but what does this have to do with HImages (Halcon)? 
Example 1 takes a `System.Drawing.Image`,
Example 2 loads a file from disk with `Image.FromFIle()`,  but I'm using `HalconDotNet.HImage` and need to make it into byte[] exactly like Image.FromFile("image.png") would do, with assumed compressions intact.